# What are the best practices for GRANDstack installation in Azure?

Tags: azure, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, grandstack

I have to start a GRANDstack (GrapQL, React, Apollo, Neo4j Database) projet from scratch in Azure.

I know that for Neo4j Database I can install a Virtual Machine on Azure.

But for GraphQL, React and Apollo I don't know what are the best pratices to install them in Azure.

For example, do I have to install Azure app service, Azure functions ?

I don't know how do I have to put each component of GRANDstack in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo can be hosted in [Azure Functions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/azure-functions/) or you can use a web framework such as [Express or Koa](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/middleware/) which can be run in an [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code?tabs=bash&WT.mc_id=javascript-00000-aapowell).

For the React component, if you're using an App Service, then you would host it out of the web framework you're using (Express, Koa, etc.) to host the static assets that are generated when converting the JSX to JavaScript.

Neo4j has [docs on deploying to Azure](https://neo4j.com/users/microsoft-azure/).